# Display a menu into a colored stripe

Tags: html, css

I have a problem when i try to insert my menu in a div tag. I want to display a dark blue stripe (called Navbar-primary in my example) and inside this stripe I want to display my menu. For the moment I have this result :

[Menu out of the stripe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nvdii.png)

This is the html of the stripe :

```
<header class="main-header">
    <div class="navbar-secundary">navbar-secundary
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-primary">navbar-primary
        <app-navbar></app-navbar>
    </div>

</header>
```

(in the app-navbar tag I have my menu)

and this is the css of the stripe :

```
.main-header .navbar-secundary {
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}

.navbar-secundary {
    background-color: 
#000f2f;
color:
    #fff;
    font-family: DINNCondMedium,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
}

header .navbar-secundary .wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


.main-header .nav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    letter-spacing: -.31em;
    text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
}



.main-header > .navbar-primary {
    position: relative;
}

.main-header .navbar-primary, .main-header .navbar-secundary {
    background-color: 
#000f2f;
color:
    #fff;
    font-family: DINNCondMedium,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
}
```

and this is my app-navbar html :

```
<nav class="menu">
    <ul class="inline">
        <li><a href="#">Acceuil</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Nous contacter</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Nos tarifs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">L'aquarium</a>
            <ul class="list">
                <li><a href="#">ENTRÉE 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ENTRÉE 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ENTRÉE 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

With the app-navbar css :

```
nav.menu {
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 18px;
}

/*
 * on s'occupe ici des dimension du menu
 */
nav.menu ul {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
    list-style-type: none; /* pour enlever les asterix devant les menu pour de l'esthetique */
}

/*
 * ici on design les sous menu
 */
nav.menu ul li {
    width: 250px; /* taille des case */
    box-sizing: border-box; /*  le padding et la bordure n'augmentent plus la largeur de l'element*/
    height: 60px;
    padding:20px 0px;
    background-color: #EEE; /* on met la couleur gris */
    text-align: center; /* on aligne le text */
    border: 1px solid black; /* on met des bordure noir */
    margin: 20px;
}

nav.menu ul.inline > li {
    float: left;
    background-image: url(/assets/image/dolphin-logo.png); /*you might need to change the url*/
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: blue;
    /* border-bottom: none; */
}

nav.menu ul.list > li {
    width: 251px;
    float: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: none;
}

nav.menu ul.list > li:last-child {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black; /* on met une bordure noir en bas de la derniere case de la sous list */ 
}

nav.menu ul ul {
    display: none; /* pour cacher le sous menu lorsque l'on est pas dessus */
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: 0px;
}


/* on va specifier ce quil se passe lors du survol de la souris grace a :hover */
nav.menu ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block; /* permet a ce que le sous menu s'affiche en bloc quand on passe la souris dessus */
}

nav.menu ul li:hover {
    background-color: #EFAE00; /* met la couleur lors du survol */
}

hr {
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;

    /* ligne de couleur degrader en violet et jaune */
    background: linear-gradient(90deg,
        purple 10%, yellow 20%, purple 30%,
yellow 40%, purple 50%, yellow 60%,
purple 70%, yellow 80%, purple 90%, yellow 100%);
}
```

Can you help me please ?

Comment: can you share `<app-navbar></app-navbar>` code ?

Comment: Yes I will update my post

Comment: Ok so what do you want to achieve in this https://jsfiddle.net/rzqpa8g7/ ?? can you please explain little bit more

Comment: the link you posted is exactly what I want. But in my case, my app-navbar appears out of the blue stripe whereas in the html code I wrote it into the stripe tag.

Comment: there is something wrong in your code. do you added any other external css file ? like bootstrap library ?

Comment: I have the app-navbar css. I will update the post with it

Comment: When I remove (in the app-navbar css) the field float: left in the tag named nav.menu ul.inline > li, I get this result https://jsfiddle.net/bqk03d1x/6/
This is what I want but now the tabs are not in the same line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I havn't tested it, but the problem is probably the `float:left`.
Read more about floats: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float

There are multiple different sollutions without floating. I think for your needs this would be the best:

=> Replace the `float: left` with `display: inline-flex`

This will not solve all your problems, but perhaps it will set you on the right track.

Read more about flex content: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

Post Scriptum:
considder using `position: relative` on your `nav.menu ul ul`. That will allow you to position the hover dropdown sub-menu relative to the li-item where it is ment to be attached to.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was the solution I searched !